# Sending HTML blocks as parameters in ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I've written a paginating repeater for ASP.NET MVC 4. It has a render method that takes arguments for the header, footer, body and separator sections to render, like so (much simplified for readability):

```
public IHtmlString Render(Func<TViewModel, object> header, Func<TViewModel, object> body, Func<TViewModel, object> footer)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    // Code to render including calling the parameter objects, something like this:
    sb.Append(header(null));
    foreach (var item in items)
        sb.Append(body(item));
    sb.Append(footer(null));

    return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

Now, I want to use this method in a Razor template and include actual template parts as the parameters. This works great for a scenario like this, where I either only use a pure lambda expression or a oneliner as the template:

```
@Model.Render(body:
    item => Html.Partial("InvoiceListView", item)
, separator:
    @<hr />
)
```

However, if I want to do something more complex, like structure a table and populate it, I just can't get Razor to realize that I want to send those multiple lines of template as a parameter.

I thought that maybe this would work:

```
@Model.Render(body: item => 
    @<text>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.ArticleNr
            </td>
        </tr>
    </text>
);
```

But no luck there. Anyone got any suggestions? Or am I tough out of luck - is it impossible to write repeaters like these in Razor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a look on this article:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx

Hope it helps!

**Edit:**

You could use some wrapper instead of direct using a lambda expression

```
@helper Foo(object item)
{
    <tr>
        ...
    </tr>
}

@Model.Render(body: Foo)
```

Comment: Actually, yes, that did help, and I'm quite surprised it did, because I thought I had tried every variant possible of the constructs. My main problem seems to have occurred as soon as I tried to use named parameters. I don't know if that's because I need to change the template definition of the arguments, or if it's just plain incompatible. If I leave out the named arguments and just use positional, though, I can include a template by just prefixing it with the @ character (and no <text></text> as in my example above).

Thanks though!